# Filters from database in PHP

Tags: php

```
echo 'Qname : <select id ="selector">';
$s = mysql_query('SELECT qid,qname FROM q_table ORDER BY qname');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($s))
{
  $filter = $row['qname'];
  $filterid = $row['qid']; 
  echo '<option value='.$filterid.'>'.$filter.'</option>';

echo '</select>';

echo '<div id='.$filterid.' class="colors" style="display:none;">';
echo '<table>
            <tr><th>USERID</th>
                <th>QNAME</th>
            </tr>';
$publishedqnames = mysql_query('SELECT qid, qname, quserid FROM pub_q'); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($publishedqnames))
{
   $qid = $row['qid'];
   $qname = $row['qname'];
   $quserid = $row['quserid'];
   echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$quserid.'</td>
            <td>'.qname.'</td> 
         </tr>';
}
echo '</table></div>';
}
```

when I select qname, the div of that selected filter(filter and qname are same) needs to get displayed
JQUERY FILE

```
   $(function() 
{
    $('#selector').change(function(){
        $('.colors').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

Rightnow Iamn't able to display the correct qid with correct div

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
echo 'Qname : <select id ="selector">';
$s = mysql_query('SELECT qid,qname FROM q_table ORDER BY qname');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($s))
{
    $filter = $row['qname'];
    $filterid = $row['qid']; 
    echo '<option value='.$filterid.'>'.$filter.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
?>
<script>
 $(function() 
{
    $('#selector').change(function(){
        $('.colors').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});

</script>
<?php

echo '<table>
            <tr><th>USERID</th>
                <th>QNAME</th>
            </tr>';
$publishedqnames = mysql_query('SELECT qid, qname, quserid FROM pub_q'); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($publishedqnames))
{
   $qid = $row['qid'];
   $qname = $row['qname'];
   $quserid = $row['quserid'];
   echo '<div id='.$filterid.' class="colors" style="display:none;">';
   echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$quserid.'</td>
            <td>'.qname.'</td> 
         </tr>';
   echo '</div>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

please let me know if not working

Comment: *"Try this:"* is a [subpar answer decoration](http://stuck.include-once.org/#help10). Instead please add a slim explanation of *what* your code does / changed, *why* you'd recommend it, or *how* you came to the conclusion.

Comment: Abid Hussain@Thank You for your answer, the code wasn't working. When I select the option, it shows nothing and I want to let you know Iam using a different js file and linking up in the file

Comment: i have improve my answer please take a look and try again

Comment: Ya when I select the last qname, it is displaying all the qname at a time but not happening for previous qname

Comment: your first while loop Curly bracket close in end of the your code see your old code.

Comment: When I select the last qname from select option, all the qnames are listed at a time. I think this isn't running in a loop

Comment: after end of first while loop then write your jquery and another code